# How to write Gradle plugin to cut down build.gradle file

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

A bit of Context first:
I am working on migrating my companies projects to be built by Gradle.
One thing, that this results in, is having redundancy in my build.gradle files,
as I am configuring the same Skeleton over and over again.
This includes:

- Setting the java-,maven-publish- and org.sonarcube-plugin
- Configuring the repositories to be mavenCentral and our private Artifactory Repo
- Configuring the publishing block, that is all the same, except for the artifactId
- Building a Manifest inside the Jar block (using helper Methods, to correctly build the Manifests   classpath)
- Helper Methods
- two Tasks
- two dependsOn statements

build.gradle file as of now:

```
plugins {
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.2.0"
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'java' 
}

group = 'group'
version = 'version'
sourceCompatibility = '11'
ext.artifactName = 'ProjectName'

// Where to look for dependencies:
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven{
        credentials{
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
}
// Where to publish what Artifacts to:
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'group'
            artifactId = 'ProjectName'
            String buildEnvVar = System.env.BUILDENVIRONMENT
            if(buildEnvVar == null){
                version = 'LOCAL BUILD'
            }else{
                version = 'version'
            }
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            // change to point to your repo, e.g. http://my.org/repo
            name = "gradle-dev"
            url = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
            credentials{
                username = "${artifactory_user}"
                password = "${artifactory_password}"
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {...}

jar { 
    // configuration of variables
    String dateString = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ")
    String localBuild = "LOCAL BUILD by " + System.getProperty("user.name") + " on " + dateString
    String buildEnvVar = System.env.BUILDENVIRONMENT
    String buildEnvironment
    String classpath = createCP()
    if(buildEnvVar == null){
        buildEnvironment = localBuild 
        archiveName = "ProjectName"
    }else{
        buildEnvironment = buildEnvVar
        archiveFileName= "ProjectName_" + version + ".jar"
        
        delete fileTree("build/libs") {
            include('*')
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes (
            "Main-Class": "org.example.foo",
            "Specification-Title" : "ProjectName",
            "Specification-Vendor" : "blab",
            "Specification-Version" : "Spec-version", 
            "Implementation-Title" : "$System.env.JOB_NAME",
            "Implementation-Version" : "Impl-version",
            "Implementation-Vendor" : "blub",
            "Implementation-Vendor-Id" : "blob",
            "Implementation-Url" : "bleb",
            "Build-By" : buildEnvironment,
            'Class-Path': classpath
        )
    }
}

String createCP () {
    // super secret can't share
}

// will suffix the jars with release or debug, depending on it being compiled with or without debug-information
project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady{
    boolean isDebug = project.gradle.taskGraph.getAllTasks().join(' ').contains('debugJar')
    compileJava.options.debug = isDebug
    String suffix = isDebug? "debug" : "release"
    String fullJarName = "$artifactName-$suffix" + ".jar"
    
    jar.setProperty('archiveName', fullJarName)
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

task debugJar() {}
debugJar.dependsOn(jar)

//Downloads all Jars the project depends on, and saves them in buildDirectory/output/libs if the gradle build command is executed.

 task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "${buildDir}/output/libs"
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
}

build.dependsOn(copyToLib)
```

what I want to achive:

```
plugins {
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.12.RELEASE'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.2.0"
    id 'maven-publish'
    id 'java'
    id 'mySuperPlugin'
}

// Configure mySuperPlugin
mySuperPlugin {
    artifactId = 'xyz'
    mainClass = 'org.example.foo'
    version = 'version'
    stuffFromOtherTasks = ...
}

// Where to look for dependencies:
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven{
        credentials{
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }
}

dependencies {...}
```

Most of the values are the same.
The ones that aren't are passed in via Environment-Variables (Jenkins-JobName,...),
or get determined through helper Methods.
I reckon, that i will most likely not end up with a buildfile like the one above,
but atleast some of the buildfile must be outsourceable.

I know as of now, that i can create seperate Tasks in a plugin, like comparing two files, that have been passed. What I didn't find a solution to yet:

- Can I modify the Jar Task of the project applying the plugin, inside the plugin?
- How do I pass Outputs from other Tasks into my plugins tasks?
- How do I access the applying projects data (i.e. the runtimeClasspath)
- Is a plugin even what i want to do, or is there another way of cutting down the build.gradle file?

I am relatively unexperienced with gradle. I have read through quite a bit of the docs and other postings, but chances are i just overlooked some best-practice way of doing certain things.
Therefore, feel free to criticize my buildfile aswell as my approach!

Comment: This "understanding gradle" playlist imho is the best, most up to date resource from a guy who worked on gradle https://youtube.com/@jjohannes it covers everything you are asking in easy steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a couple of ways.  And this comes down to if your project is composed of multiple sub-projects or if they are stand alone projects.  For stand alone projects you can do the following in your settings.gradle file:

```
includeBuild("../common-project/build.gradle")
```

The common project would just house the common `build.gradle` file, and you'd declare all of the items you want to share in there.  It would look like a normal build.gradle file.

That would require that each project share the common configuration from another project, but wouldn't require any additional projects be checked out.  Just the common project and the project itself.  For more details see:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html

If you have more of a multi-project build like say many micro-services or subprojects that make up a larger project then using multi-project setup and declare the common pieces in the `allprojects` closure in the root build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    plugin: java
    plugin: web

    repositories {
      ....
    }

    dependencies {
       ....
    }
}
```

In the multi-project case you'd have to check out the top level project and all subprojects.  Your folder layout might look like this:

```
- my-project
  - service-1
      src
      build.gradle
  - service-2
      src
      build.gradle
  - service-3
      src
      build.gradle
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

In the multi-project setup service1, service2, and service3 would be declared in the `settings.gradle` file using `include` like so:

```
rootProject.name = 'my-project'
include `service1`
include `service2`
include `service3`
```

In a multi-project setup you'd typically house that in a single source repository as oppose to using `includeBuild` where each project would belong to a separate source code repo.  The former way  forces you to checkout the appropriate number of projects in the multi-project case.  But, in the `includeBuild` case the developer would have to know to check out minimum of 2 projects.

Comment: You're better using convention plugins than `allprojects`

Comment: FWIW I've used both.  I've been happy with using allprojects to share configuration, tasks, etc.  And I've had to switch to using plugins to accomplish things that can't be done with allprojects.  But plugins come with more overhead, and more process.  buildSrc can help limit that overhead.

Comment: @chubbsondubs As by your first suggestion the projects are standalone Projects and I get your Point, but with that i can Only outsource Tasks right?. So the Jar Manipulation might even work, but how do I pass in the Parameters?

Comment: I think you should be to use the extension objects to provide customizations to a shared set of properties for things.  So things like publishing, credentials, etc could all be specified through extensions on your project and the build being included would just refer to those extensions within the skeleton config in it.  You might be able to use properties file if extensions didn't work.  I know that for a project I have extensions are leveraged to customize an allprojects block as well as plugins.

Comment: Looking at your code above in the jar config I'd say you want to move most of that outside of that block, and just move that logic to the outside.  That way you don't really need to modify the jar config.  Just have some properties you refer to, and that outside logic will set those.  You may have to move away from a specific debugJar task in favor of properties to signify what you want.  That way you don't need to wait until the taskGraph has finished to parse it.

Comment: @chubbsondubs as of now i refactored most of my buildfile, but I am struggling to get rid of the createCP() call from the jar task. Because if I set an ext.classPath variable, it is evaluated to late and the classpath in my Manifest is empty (even though I specified that jar depends on createCP). If I try to wrap the manifest-block in a doLast{}, the resulting Manifest is just empty. So how do I achieve the wanted behaviour of: read the dependencies -> ... -> createCP() -> ... -> jar

Comment: @NoelUzunbeycan I wonder if something like convention might help you.  https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#applying_conventions